# Passing attributes while using a partial inside another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have three models - Company, User(Using Devise) & Donation.Donation is a rich join between Company And User using :through.
I have a partial form for creating a new donation inside show view of company which takes three attributes - company_id, user_id and the amount. 
The code for the form inside the view is as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for @donation do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="well">
        <h1 align="center" class="amountHead">Donate</h1>
        <form class="form-inline donate-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">&#8377;</div>
              <%= f.input :amount, label: false, placeholder: 'Amount in Rupees' %>
              <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="actions" style="text-align: center">
            <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How do I pass the user_id and company_id using the id of the current user and the ID of the company they are viewing automatically when the user enters the amount.

donation_controller.rb

```
class DonationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @donations = Donation.all
  end

  def new
    @donation = Donation.new()
  end

  def create
    @donation = Donation.new(donation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @donation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @donation, notice: 'Donation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @donation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @donation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def donation_params
    params.require(:donation).permit(:amount,:user_id,:company_id)
  end
end
```

company_controller.rb

```
def show
    @donation = Donation.new
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hidden_field` in the `form` for `user_id` and `company_id`

```
f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id }
f.input :company_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @company.id }
```

You need to define `@company = Company.find(params[:id])` in `companies_controller` ***show*** method for this.

Comment: Thanks.....It solved the problem!!!....I actually thought that I had to do something in the controllers...but it turned out to be the view.Very simple and elegant solution!!!